# Golang: Validate Struct Fields in Slice Items

Tags: json, validation, go, struct, slice

I'm new to Golang.

golang version: **1.17.8**

validator: "**github.com/go-playground/validator/v10**"

I want to validate an incoming JSON payload after loaded into nested struct data structure.
Here's my incoming JSON payload,

```
  {
  "name": "Yomiko",
  "address": {
    "city": "Tokyo",
    "street": "Shibaura St"
  },
  "children":[
    {
      "lastName": "Takayashi"
    }
  ],
  "isEmployed": false
  }
```

Here's my user.go file,

```
package main

type User struct {
    Name    string
    Address *Address `validate:"required"`
    Children []*Child
    IsEmployed *bool `validate:"required"`
}
type Address struct {
    City     string `validate:"required"`
    Street  string `validate:"required"`
}

type Child struct {
    Title string `validate:"required"`
    FirstName string
    LastName string `validate:"required"`
}
```

Here's my test function,

```
func TestUserPayload(t *testing.T) {
    actualUserPayload := NewUserPayloadFromFile("userpayload.json")

    validate := validator.New()
    err := validate.Struct(actualUserPayload)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error("Validation Error: ", err)
    }

}
```

This test passes. However, I expected it to fail as **Child.Title** is marked as **required**. I expected the following error,

```
Validation Error:  Key: 'Child.Title' Error:Field validation for 'Title' failed on the 'required' tag
```

However, when I loop through the children slice and validate each child struct as follows the test fails as expected,

```
func TestUserPayload(t *testing.T) {
    actualUserPayload := NewUserPayloadFromFile("userpayload.json")

    validate := validator.New()
    err := validate.Struct(actualUserPayload)
    if err != nil {
        t.Error("Validation Error: ", err)
    }

    children := actualUserPayload.Children

    for _, child := range children {
        err := validate.Struct(child)
        if err != nil {
            t.Error("Validation Error: ", err)
        }
    }

}
```

Is there a straightforward way to do this validation of the items in a slice of structs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation of the validator package](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-playground/validator/v10#hdr-Dive), you can use `dive` in your struct tag to get this behavior. This causes the validator to also validate the nested struct/slice/etc.

So you would need to update your `User` struct to this:

```
type User struct {
    Name       string
    Address    *Address `validate:"required"`
    Children   []*Child `validate:"dive"`
    IsEmployed *bool    `validate:"required"`
}
```

Here it is working in [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/xp445t9Da19)

Comment: In addition, to validate that the slice field exists *and* validate all elements, use `validate:"required,dive"`, `required` goes before `dive`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin), `binding:required,dive` works for me:

```golang
type Child struct {
  Name string `json:"name" binding:"required"`
}

type Body struct {
  Children []Child `json:"children" binding:"required,dive"` 
}
```